# MS SQL 2000 ODBC PHP slow connect() and slow odbc_fetch_row()

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

When i `odbc_connect()` to MS SQL with PHP using ODBC in **local network(not host)**, the connection takes about **11 seconds**. Here is the code of my connection:

```
function __construct(){
    $connstr = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=serv;Database=Base;";
    $this->lnk = odbc_connect($connstr, "login", "passs");
}
```

And when i `odbc_fetch_row()` it also takes about **5 seconds**. Here is my result function code:

```
function manual($query){
    $result = odbc_exec($this->lnk, $query);// or exit(odbc_error);
    for($i = 1; $i<odbc_num_fields($result)+1; $i++){
        $arr_row[] = odbc_field_name($result,$i);
    }
    while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
        foreach($arr_row as $name){
            $ownsql_result[$name][] = trim(odbc_result($result, $name));
        }
    }
    odbc_free_result($result);
    return $ownsql_result; 
}
```

Im Using **WAMP** on **Windows 7** and **MS SQL 2000** on other PC **Windows Server 2003** in same **local network**... Plz guys help out

Comment: You. Are. Using. *MS SQL **2000***???

Comment: Yes... and its a must ^^ may be i can try 2005 server, but i think ill have compatibility problem, couse this sql server is used by another very old version program... and its a big problem to upgrade it... i need to solve this on what i have

Comment: Oh, sorry! I have heard of things like that (huge companies still using IE6, because it is basically not an option to upgrade, for example...).

Comment: Okay. A couple of questions: 1. Exactly *how large* is your DB/table? 2. Windows Server 2003? What are the specs? (unlikely, but the problem could (conceivably) be because the server PC is slow, or just running low on RAM?)

Comment: No... its a huge financial program... so it will be a problem

Comment: ? I was asking how fast the Windows Server 2003 PC is?

Comment: 1 table 18k rows other 300k rows... and i do like left join and top 9... and result is less than 1kb of pure data... the query in query analyzer is all ok... Intel Xeon 2.4Ghz and 4gb RAM...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in MSSQL SERVER VERSION... i changed it from 2000 to 2005 and all worked fiine

Answer (score 0):

We were using SQL Server 2000 up to last year and php's MSSQL librairy was working fine.
Try to switch from ODBC to MSSQL.